# Perl variable in XPath expression

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, xml-libxml

How can I use a Perl variable inside a XPath expression using the XML::LibXML module's findnodes() function? This is what I got:

```
my $variable = 1;
foreach my $node1 ($doc->findnodes('par/par1/par2[@id = $variable]'))
{

}
```

But it doesn’t seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: [`"it doesn't work"`](http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html) and its family of related expressions are rather useless and should be avoided in these kinds of forums, unless you elaborate and add relevant information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot interpolate using single quotes, you must use double quotes, or another form of quoting that does interpolate

```
"par/par1/par2[\@id = $variable]"
```

However, I assume that `@id` is not a variable, so you must escape its sigil, or it will be treated as a variable as well. If you are using `use strict` -- which you always should -- this will lead to a compiler error.

The [other forms of quoting](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) that might be mentioned

- `qq()`, which is exactly like double quote
- Heredocs

Answer (score 1):

edit: kudos to TLP

Haritz,

Does changing the single quotes around the XPath expression to double quotes work?

I came here looking for exactly the same solution and I tried it in one of my scripts and I think it works the same with double quotes instead of single quotes, but I'm interested to know if it works for you too.

```
my $variable = 1;
foreach my $node1 ($doc->findnodes("par/par1/par2[\@id = $variable]"))
{

}
```